# Bash programming with filesystem functions

Tags: bash, ssh, directory

I have been busy this week trying to wrap my head around a little Bash program to migrate a CMS from one server to another. The reasopn for this is because I have more tha 40 of these to do, and need to get it done in a timely manner, thus the Bash idea.

Needless to say, I have run into a couple of problems so far, but one of them has halted my development completetly, directory checking.

No I have tried a couple of methods and none of them seem to work really. The catch is that I have to check the folder on a remote server via ssh. Here my example:

```
ExSshRsa=~/.ssh/id_rsa
ExSshPort=22
ExSshHost=localhost
ExRoot=/var/www/
echo -n "Verifying Root access $ExRoot..."
SSHRoot='ssh -i $ExSshRsa -p $ExSshPort $ExSshHost [ -d $ExRoot ] || exit 1 '
echo $SSHRoot 
if [ "$SSHRoot" -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "OK"
    else
        echo "FAIL"
fi
```

I get the Error: **[: : integer expression expected**

Does the [ or test not resturn a 0 which is numerical. ?

Comment: You realize that you're not running that ssh call, just displaying it, right?

Comment: I changed the line to 
SSHRoot=$( ssh -i $ExSshRsa -p $ExSshPort $ExSshHost [ -d $ExRoot ] && echo "0" && exit 0 || echo "1" && exit 1 )
and it seems to work...?!?

Comment: how I would love to change the typo in the title...

Comment: Oh, hadn't spotted it :-) You should be able to with the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7608766/edit) link right under your question. Is it preventing you from doing that edit? (If so, what is the error?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing strings as arguments to a remote host is not trivial; you need to [use arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/096). A test example:

```
declare -a cmd=(touch "file name with spaces")
printf -v escaped_cmd_str '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"
ssh localhost $escaped_cmd
ssh localhost ls # Should return "file name with spaces" on a separate line
```

So your case should be:

```
ExSshRsa=~/.ssh/id_rsa
ExSshPort=22
ExSshHost=localhost
ExRoot=/var/www/
echo -n "Verifying Root access $ExRoot..."

declare -a cmd=( '[' -d "$ExRoot" ']' ) # Need to quote "[" since it's a Bash-specific symbol
printf -v escaped_cmd_str '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"

if ssh -i "$ExSshRsa" -p "$ExSshPort" "$ExSshHost" $escaped_cmd
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
```

This is a rare case where using [unquoted variable expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, as this would be the next problem I was going to get, but first I am trying to get the subjective programming to work...

Comment: Storing `escaped_cmd` as an array isn't buying you anything here over `printf -v escaped_cmd_str '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"`, and passing ssh `"$escaped_cmd_str"`. Keep in mind that ssh concatenates together all the strings it's passed as arguments -- so you're generating an escaped string, breaking it into pieces, and letting ssh reassemble it... to what end?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice shortcut!

Answer (score 1):

change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` and look at the output...

1. you are storing a string in variable `SSHRoot` using single quotes, meaning that no variables will be expanded, i.e. a `$` is still a `$`. Use double quotes instead, i.e. `"`
2. to store the output from a command in bash, use

   var=$(cmd)
3. the exist status of a command is stored in the variable `$?`. Do a check on that after the ssh-command
4. you are never executing the ssh-command in your code

Great link [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) for bash-programming

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
ExSshRsa=~/.ssh/id_rsa
ExSshPort=22
ExSshHost=localhost
ExRoot=/var/www/
echo -n "Verifying Root access $ExRoot..."
cmd="bash -c \"[ -d $ExRoot ] || exit 1\""
SSHRoot="ssh -i $ExSshRsa -p $ExSshPort $ExSshHost ${cmd}"
$SSHRoot 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "OK"
    else
        echo "FAIL"
fi
```

The variables weren't being replaced in your `SSHRoot` variable as it's in single quotes. Also, you weren't passing an executable command, so that's why I use `bash -c` above. It will run the bash commands inside the quoted string.

`$?` stores the exit value of the last command, in this case the `SSHRoot` one.

Comment: is your way better? My way seems to work, but I much rather do it the right way...
`SSHRoot=$( ssh -i $ExSshRsa -p $ExSshPort $ExSshHost [ -d $ExRoot ] && echo "0" && exit 0 || echo "1" && exit 1 )`

Comment: @WillemP.Botha better is subjective in a lot of cases. If you're happy with what you have then fire ahead. I think my solution is much easier to read.

Comment: I like the subjective approach, and am trying to re-write it like this, it makes for much better reading

Comment: without the $SSHRoot before the **if** the script does not work, this really makes no sense anymore... maybe I can use the variable expansion in a subjective approach..

Comment: Sorry Willem, are you saying your version or mine doesn't work? I tested mine this morning and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
ExSshRsa=~/.ssh/id_rsa
ExSshPort=22
ExSshHost=localhost
ExBase='/tmp/'
ExRoot='one space/'
declare -a AExRoot
for argR in "${ExRoot[@]}"
    do
        ExRoot+=($(printf %q "$argR"))
    done
clear
FRoot=( $ExBase${ExRoot[@]} )
echo -n "Verifying Root access $FRoot..."
SSHRootTest="bash -c \"[ -d $FRoot ] && echo 0 && exit 0 || echo 1 && exit 1\""
SSHRoot=$( ssh -i $ExSshRsa -p $ExSshPort $ExSshHost ${SSHRootTest})
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -en "\e[1;32mOK\e[0;37;m..."
    else
        echo -en "\e[1;31mFAIL\e[0;37;m..."
fi
sleep 1
if [ -w $FRoot ]
    then 
        echo -e "\e[1;32mwritable\e[0;37;m"
    else 
        echo -e "\e[1;31mNOT writeable\e[0;37;m"
fi
echo -e "\e[0;m"
exit 0
```

So I have incorporated all of the suggestions so far and have one last problem, the `FRoot` is not getting populated by the complete array values. Other than that I think it now has the subjective approach as suggested @john-keyes, the proper expansion @frederik and the crazy space escapes @l0b0

Comment: actually, reading it now, the write test is not working as it is testing to the local file system, but that is besides the point, I can fix that the same way I did the previous test, the important part is trying to get the array to concatenate all the values back into the `FRoot` variable with the quoted space values....